# Want to upgrade 4.2.2 to 4.4 (GT6060)

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 4.2-jelly-bean

I'm using Samsung Grand Neo(GT9060) with 4.2.2. Now I want to upgrade it with 4.4.But there is no update available. Is it possible to upgrade??if so then how??

Answer (score 0):

#### Hello Nini

Some phones only uses its original Android Version (Stock ROM) because of some hardware incompatabilty. Like the mainboard, RAM and Processor, they may not be ready, or it can't support the next Android Version. 


And if you want to taste the new flavor of Android Versions, Yes and it is possible but it also come into unsupported devices and your phone maybe one of them. Try searching for your device model on how to install Custom ROMs or you may want to read  [this](http://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-install-custom-rom-android/)  thread.